# Time interval between two dates with Perl

Tags: perl, datetime

I'm adding two dates and trying to calculate the time, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Error parsing time at /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.30.0/Time/Piece.pm line 598.
```

I install Time::Piece with cpan:  `cpan Time::Piece`.

This my code:

```
our @months = qw( 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 );
our @days = qw(Domingo Segunda Treça Quarta Quinta Sexta Sabado Domingo);

 ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$day,$isdst) = localtime();
 our $ano = "2021";
 our $day = "$mday";
 our $mes = $months[$mon];
 our $data = $mes."-".$day."-".$ano; 
 our $horario = $hour.":".$min.":".$sec;
 our $horario2 = $hour.":".$min.":".$sec;
 our $data1 = $ano."-".$mes."-".$day;
 our $data2 = $day."/".$mes."/".$ano;
 our $str1 = 'Execution completed at '.$data2.' '.$horario.' AM';

 our @mes = qw( Jan Feb Mar APr May Jun Jul Agu Sep Oct Nov Dec );
 our @days = qw(Domingo Segunda Treça Quarta Quinta Sexta Sabado Domingo);

($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime();

$nomeMes = $mes[$mon];

our @mes = qw( Jan Feb Mar APr May Jun Jul Agu Sep Oct Nov Dec );
our @days = qw(Domingo Segunda Treça Quarta Quinta Sexta Sabado Domingo);

($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime();

our $data2 = $day."/".$mes."/".$ano; 
our $horario = $hour.":".$min.":".$sec;

my $str2 = 'Execution completed at '.$data2.' '.$horario.' AM';
my @times = map Time::Piece->strptime(/(\d.+M)/, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p'), $str1, $str2;

my $delta = $times[1] - $times[0];

$tempo = $delta->pretty;
```

What am I doing wrong? What can I do to make this function work?

Comment: Tip: All of those `our` are wrong and should be `my`. `our` is used for variables that need to be seen outside of the package. Basically, use `our` for `@EXPORT_OK` and similar when using Exporter, and that's it.

Comment: With Perl 5.30, you shouldn't need to install [Time::Piece](http://p3rl.org/Time::Piece), it should be part of Perl itself (unless you are on a distribution that crippled the Perl package).

Comment: ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings;`! This spits out a long list of issues for your code.

Comment: @ikegami... I use strict and warnnigs, but not receive message about Time::PIece.

Comment: uh, your code doesn't even compile with `use strict; use warnings;`. And are you sauing you just ignored the tons of warnings it spits out?

Comment: Just replace "my" to "our", no more. :(

Comment: The problem is Time::Piece, but.. why?

Comment: No, it isn't. Giving it a date-time of 13 am on the 20th month is. I already explained that in my answer.

Comment: I solve the problem. Thanks very much for help. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The matched pattern of `$str1` is `20/12/2021 13:58:3 AM`

Problems:

- There's no 20th month
- There's no 13 AM
- Can give the wrong answer near a switch from Daylight-Saving Time.

Also, there's a couple of problems `strptime` ignores:

- You should be using `%I` instead of `%H` for 12-hour time.
- There's a lack of leading zeros where they are normally expected (minutes and seconds).

---

You appear to be asking the following:

> Given the year, month, day, hour, minute and second components of a local time, how do I obtain the corresponding epoch time so I can perform a difference?

To achieve this, use [Time::Local](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Local)'s `timelocal*`.

```perl
use Time::Local qw( timelocal_posix );

my $time = timelocal_posix( $sec, $min, $hour, $day, $month - 1, $year - 1900 );
```

You could also use [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime). This more powerful module can give you differences in amounts other than seconds.

Either way, you will still have problems near a switch from DST. There's simply not enough information to address that. That's the problem with dealing with local times with no offset.

Answer (score -1):

I use the script:

```
our $str2 = $ano.'/'.$mes.'/'.$day.' '.$hour.':'.$min.':'.$sec.'.267-05:00';

my @times = map Time::Piece->strptime( s/\..*//r, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'), $str1, $str2; 
our $delta = $times[1] - $times[0];
print $delta->pretty;
```

It's work.

Thanks very much Ikegami for help.

Comment: Ah, that's what you're trying to achieve? See my updated answer.